# How to read 2E2, 2E4, 3E2, 3E4 as string from csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

If I use

```
read_csv ('data.csv', dtype=str)
```

Python is converting my data:

```
2E2 =200.0, 2E4=20000.0
```

How to stop this conversion?

Comment: What are data inside the csv? add an example of it the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to supply the column to the data you want converted. Here's a mockup i made with your two values:

```
 pd.read_csv('102.txt', dtype={'what': str})
```

output:

```
  what        do
0  2E2 20000.000
```

and

```
pd.read_csv('102.txt', dtype={'what': str, 'do': str})                                                                                                                              

  what   do
0  2E2  2E4
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. If I supply column it is working, but I have more than 200 columns and the data filled in above mentioned format randomly. Is there any alternative to suppress this conversion for entire file?

Comment: @charansagar you can do  pd.read_csv('102.txt', dtype=str) but that converts everything to strings